# Python __future__ methods

Tags: python, printing

Would it be correct to say that if 'print' is not listed as one of the methods in

```
__future__.__dict__.keys()
```

then the version of Python that I am using does not supply the future print function?  (I am using Python 2.5.5.)

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: I want to make my 2.5.5 code effortlessly portable when Google App Engine supports a newer version of Python.  That's why.

Comment: `2to3` is too much effort for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, but that would be `print_function`, and that was introduced in Python 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

*Almost* correct.  The feature is called `print_function`, not print.

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import __future__
>>> __future__.print_function
_Feature((2, 6, 0, 'alpha', 2), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 65536)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is correct.  <strike>But a better way to do that check would be:</strike>

<strike>try:
        from **future** import print_function
    except ImportError:
        print "print is a stmt"</strike>

You cannot do the above way of importing and checking for print_function. The ways available seems, checking with sys.version and checking the `__future__` dictionary as you are doing.

Comment: `SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file`